# Updating UIButton State in TableViewCell Changes other Rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

My table view contains a uibutton inside each row and depending if a user has redeemed it I would like to change it's image and whether it is disabled or enabled.

When a user purchases an item (say item 0 which is the first row at all times) I want to notify my app that it should switch the image and disable the button at the specific row. I'm using NSUserDefaults to alert my tableView.

In other words if a user clicks on item 0 they are asked if they would like to redeem or cancel, if user presses redeem, I do the following:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"itemZeroRedeemed"];
[storeTableView reloadData];
```

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath I do:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"itemZeroRedeemed"]) {
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        [cell.productInfoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"itemUnlocked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.productInfoButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly in that it updates the tableView and row correctly, especially when coming back later. My issue is that farther down the list item 5 is also being updated with the new button state. How can I fix this since I only want the specified button updated?

Comment: Can you share your full cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I guess the cell farer down uses "itemZeroRedeemed" as key too. That may be caused by the cell resuing mechanism. Share more code, especially of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the cell reusing mechanism. For each cell you should reset the default status like this:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"itemZeroRedeemed"] && indexPath.row == 0) {
    [cell.productInfoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"itemUnlocked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.productInfoButton.enabled = NO;
} else {
    [cell.productInfoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"__DEFAULT_IMAGE__"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.productInfoButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Antonio! For the case where I have multiple items do I need multiple else's or just one at the bottom? For example I'm planning to do what you posted as an answer with 5 different items. Would each need its own else command as well, or just one at the bottom.

Comment: Well usually I have an initial reset block just after the cell creation/reuse, then I have multiple blocks of configuration. Mind that if the kind of cells you are going to use are a lot, it may be better to differentiate them directly in the storyboard by putting in the same UITableView multiple prototype cells with different reuse identifiers